# Set text font size of leftbarbuttonitem in iOS7

Tags: uinavigationbar

So I've been able to change the text size and color of the main text in the UINavigationBar like so:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                       UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
                                                       UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0],
                                                       }];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

However, the font size of the leftbarbuttonitem is still too large.  How do i reference the leftbarbuttonitem so that i can set the text style to it?

I've tried stuff like

```
[UINavigationBar leftBarButtonItem]
[[UINavigationBar navigationItems] leftBarButtonItem]
[[UINavigationBar appearance] leftBarButtonItem]
// and many others
etc...
```

But xcode keeps complaining that it doesn't exist, and I have not been able to reference it.

Can someone tell me how to set the text size for the leftBarButtonItem based on my code above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *) forState:(UIControlState)];`

Keep note, that the UINavigationBar uses the UIBarButtonItem, so you need to style that object when it's contained in a specific view (reference by it's class). This applies in several other places. Another use case could be this, where A, B, and C are 3 distinct UINavigationControllers

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[A class], [B class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *) forState:(UIControlState)];`

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[C class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *) forState:(UIControlState)];

In the above sample, UIBarButtonItems in UINavigationControllers A & B will receiving the similar styling whereas UINavigationController C's UIBarButtonItems will have their own distinct styling.